# Pulling Data from tables to pass into an autocompleter c#

Tags: c#, sql, autocomplete

I'm working on an autocompleter in c#, I'm using a SQL stored procedure to pull the data which is tested and working.

The issue I'm having is with my for loop which I am using the populate the auto completer.

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection col = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in TYPESDS.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            col.Add(row[i].ToString().ToUpper());
            i++;
        }
```

Above is where I have go to with regards to this, I get no errors however the code just does not work.

I have an auto completer working however this has the SQL embedded in the code and I would rather have it working using the stored procedure.

Comment: Define "does not work".  What *does* it do?  When you step through this code in your debugger, where/how does it first deviate from what you expect?  Does that loop iterate at all?  Are the values added to `col`?  What *specifically* happens?

Comment: When stepping through, the autoCompleter method runs through once then on the second run through when it comes to col.Add I get the error: IndexOutOfRange exception was unhandled

Comment: The issue is occurring due to the fact column 1 cannot be found. However, from my understanding I'm only asking it to go through the rows and column number should not change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the use of foreach() to iterate over rows, then for each row also using an indexer (i).

in the original code sample, the "row" in each iteration is a Data Row.  The default indexer on this is indexing into the COLUMNS.  So on the first row, it'll access column 0, and on the second row, it'll access column 1 and so on.

the second example works because you're using the indexer (i) on the Rows collection property of the table - so this is accessing a ROW.  on this Row you're then using the field name indexer to get the "Type" Column.

If the first example was modified to this:

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection col = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
foreach (DataRow row in TYPESDS.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    col.Add(row["Type"].ToString().ToUpper());
}
```

Then it is basically equivalent to the second (working) example.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on using foreach and got it working the following way.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < TYPESDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++ )
  {
      col.Add(TYPESDS.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Type"].ToString().ToUpper());
  }
```

I think the main issue came with not having the ["Type"] with Rows[i].